# How to create a map system for my game?

Tags: tilemap, maps

I wanted to make a small game about space.
However, I had a couple of questions [below]

How will I draw a map for my game? I would like it to contain a solar system.
How will I draw these planets?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell more about it

Comment: can YOU tell US more about it?

Comment: Or show links where you can watch this

Comment: Is the game 2d or 3d? What properties and which grade of detail do the planets have?

Comment: 2d game.The planet it will be a normal picture

Comment: When it's about creating the scenery graphics for the planets: There is [Terragen](http://www.planetside.co.uk/products/terragen3) which can generate amazing planet graphics. But it requires some learning effort and isn't cheap.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to generating content for a game, there are three approaches

1. **Create the content by hand.** Either hard-code it into the games sourcecode or write the files which store the content with a text editor. This is quite tedious and hard to maintain, but when you don't have a lot of content, it is a valid quick&dirty method.
2. **Create a map editor.** To make it more convenient to edit your game content, you create a GUI-based editor application for it. Depending on your requirements and how user-friendly you want it to be, this can be a quite large sub-project costing considerable development time, but it can pay off well in the long run. Especially because it allows you to delegate the content creation to other people who are less technically-inclined. When your game isn't that extraordinary, you could try using an existing map-editor and either adopt its format or write a converter. This can save you considerable amount of work. For tile-based 2d maps, there is [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/), for example.
3. **Create your content procedurally.** Instead of creating the content by hand, you write a program to generate the content for you based on random numbers. Making the content look naturally and interesting to play (or even playable at all) like it was generated by humans can be quite hard (again - depending on your requirements), but when you can pull it off you can create as much content as you want with the click of a button. You can also integrate the generation algorithm into the game itself and let the player generate new game worlds at will, greatly improving replay value.

Comment: Well, it's all so clear, I need more detail as to place it on the map of the planet, I'll take off more than she worked, that is, give the name may destroy them.

Comment: @user36689 I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment.